# Add custom claim onPremisesSamAccountName into access_token on Azure AD app registration Authentication

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have an Azure App registration using OAuth2 for authentication. My requirement is for the user value "onPremisesSamAccountName" to be passed on the access_token when the authentication flow happens. I'm currently testing this flow using google Oauth playground by setting the athorize and token endpoints I get from my App registration on Azure, as well as the OAuth client ID and secret.

So far I have tried to follow these Microsoft questions:

- [inlcude onpemise samaccount in azure ad claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/6472/inlcude-onpemise-samaccount-in-azure-ad-claims)
- [Azure AD - add custom claim to access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/417758/azure-ad-add-custom-claim-to-access-token)

Which explain that you have to create an Azure AD policy of type "ClaimsMappingPolicy" and link this policy to the service principal (my enterprise app registration's object Id) using Powershell. I have followed this but my custom claim appears on the id_token returned from the authentication flow rather than on the access_token.

My question, is there a way to expose a custom claim on the access_token and NOT on the id_token for an app registration using Oauth2 authentication? Is there maybe a configuration missing on my app registration that causes my custom claim to be set to the id_token?

I am **NOT** trying to set a user role to the access_token but rather exposing a custom claim that my Azure AD has for every user on the access_token during authentication.

To obtain the token, I'm using [Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground). I set my OAuth endpoints and secrets:
[image: Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground]

And then on the "Select & authorize APIs" i set it to openid:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a **policy** and assigned the policy to the Service Principal like below:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('
{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"extensionattribute1","SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/employeeid","JwtClaimType":"employeeid"}]
    }
}') -DisplayName "employeeid" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"

Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -RefObjectId 'PolicyID' -Id 'ServicePrincipalObjID'
```

[image]

***I assigned the policy to the user:***

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

{
"onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
"extensionAttribute1": "3394"
}
}
```

[image]

> **Note** that: To display the custom claim in the access token you have to generate access token for your application not any other  application (like Microsoft Graph, SharePoint etc). Refer [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/optional-claims#configure-directory-extension-optional-claims).

I **exposed an API in the Azure AD Application** and added scope:

[image]

I added API permissions:

[image]

Generated **tokens** via Postman using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:api://xxx/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

**When I decoded the access token, the custom claim displayed successfully:**

[image]

Make sure to update "**acceptMappedClaims**" as true in the Manifest of the Azure AD Application.

***I tried to generate the tokens for Microsoft Graph scope:***

```json
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

**When I decoded the access token, custom claims dint display:**

[image]

**But in ID Token the custom claims displayed:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanations! my custom value is the onPremisesSamAccountName on the user profile, would this change anything with your proposed solution? would i still need to to expose an api and set the api permission? when i attempt to add the api scope i create "extensiontest.read" along with openid to obtain my access token, i get "AADSTS90009: Application 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is requesting a token for itself. This scenario is supported only if resource is specified using the GUID based App Identifier." is there a different way to expose the onPremisesSamAccountName?

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot of how you are generating token?

Comment: When setting the scope, i was using "api://{appid}/extensiontest.read" but now i updated it to {appid}/extensiontest.read and the value shows on the access_token! I'm using Gogle's OAuth 2.0 Playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground, I will update the main question with the way I'm testing this.

Comment: Scope must be api://***/. default not api://extentiontest.read

Comment: my bad, copy-paste mistake,i used api://xxx/.default. This actually didn't work for me so i used "openid xxx/.default". I had to remove api:// because of the error i showed in my first comment. Thanks a lot!